# I am unable to run my program

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=student.mdb;DriverID=22;READONLY=true
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at withoutdsn.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: in order to jdbc to work you should import the .jar in your program.

Comment: Which Java Version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

In order to successfully execute a connection with a database through java,for example if you are using mysql follow the steps below:

Go to mysql website and download the appropriate driver for Java. 
Then go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries (in Eclipse) and click on "add external Jars".
Add the .jar you downloaded.
Before doing anything else you should be sure to set your connection right.

For example:

```
//the default port of mysql is 3306
String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb";
String login = "root";
String passwd = "toor";

Connection cn = null;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

System.out.println("Connecting to database..");

try {

    cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, passwd);
    System.out.println("Database Connected");

    st = cn.createStatement();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM impacts";
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    while (rs.next()){
            //do something
      }
  }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("Exception");
  }finally{
       if (cn != null ){
       cn.close();
        }         
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java 8 and a JDBC-ODBC Bridge Driver? Bridge drivers are deprecated and not available in Java 8. [See here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cd91e7de-998e-4a82-b843-5a0799bf00cb/jdbcodbc-bridge-driver-removed-in-java-8-what-is-best-alternative-for-accessing-ms-access?forum=accessdev).

If you want to run simple JDBC programs, instead of MS Access you could try using Java DB. Probably, Java DB works best with Netbeans IDE. There is nice tutorial [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html).